# Teechart install finishes, nothing changed

Tags: teechart

I installed

TeeChart_Standard_RADXE2Update4.exe

On my XE2 on 32 bit machine. Nothing shows in the IDE. Is there install log, or other steps I can take to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Hello Doege, Could you confirm us which exactly TeeChart Standard  version is you using? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the one from Embarcadero that comes/was bundled with Delphi XE2 professional. It is just and exe file without any other info so I don't really know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem you experiencing here, using Rad Studio XE2 update 4 and Teechart Standard for Update 4.

I would like suggest you review if you use the Rad Studio XE2 update 4 hotfix 1. Here's the link: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42282

Then, download the TeeChart Standard for update 4 from link below: 
http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28780